# Is this a form of *LaetIporous sulfurous*? Tree is in north central Virginia

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I found this while walking our dogs. Is this "chicken of the woods"?[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed Chicken-of-the-Woods - and a nice specimen! However, there are multiple species that closely resemble each other, all called "Chicken-of-the-Woods." Based on your location and the tree it is growing on (I am guessing a hemlock or pine from the bark), it is likely *Laetiporus huroniensis* (see [Emberger, 2008](https://www.messiah.edu/Oakes/fungi_on_wood/poroid%20fungi/species%20pages/Laetiporus%20huroniensis.htm)), which grows on conifers east of the Rockies ([Kuo, 2017](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/laetiporus.html)).

[image: sample image]
<sup>Fig. 1. An older *Laetiporus huroniensus* found in West Virginia. image: [Django Grootmyers](https://mushroomobserver.org/users/5157) ([CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/))</sup>

If you might eat these in the future, please read [this article (Margulies, 2006)](https://blog.mycology.cornell.edu/2006/10/31/eating-the-chicken-of-the-woods/) concerning potential toxicity. [Marley (2010)](https://isbndb.com/book/9781603582148) advises to eat only a small portion and not share your first time, and to not eat those growing on conifers (i.e., this cluster).